# How to configure Python script to change body for Splunk email alert?

Tags: python, email, alert, splunk

I have a Splunk query which returns several JSON results and that I want to save as alert, sending regular emails to a list of people.

I have created a Python script which takes as input some JSONS like the ones from the Splunk logs and beautifies the results.

How can I configure the Splunk alert so that the users get by email the beautified results? Is it possible to configure Splunk to run the Python script on the query results and put the beautified output in the email body? Should I upload the script somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well stated @IvanStarostin

The script should always be located in : $SPLUNK_HOME/bin/scripts or in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc//bin/scripts in case of an app.
When an alert triggers you can select a script to be run in the following way:

Run the desired search and then click Save as Alert. Configure how often should your search run and the conditions according to which the alert should be triggered (e.g. when results is equal to 0).

Then Select Run a script from the Add Actions menu. Enter the file name of the script that you want to run and you are set up!
You can test you script in the search bar too by piping it after your query:

....|script commandname

Answer (score 1):

If you mean running the script from the search line, this answers your question:
http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.3.3/SearchReference/Script

(NOTE: choose the right version of Splunk if you run something earlier than 6.3.3)

Comment: You should provide more info because link may become non-working